# VM2714:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem everytime I try with jquery to pass the response I have from my server to json I receive this message Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0 at. As a backend I'm using php.

I have a problem everytime I try with jquery to pass the response I have from my server to json I receive this message Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0 at. As a backend I'm using php.

```
**$('#search').keyup(function() {
    if($('#search').val()) {
      let search = $('#search').val();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'tak_search.php',
        data: {search},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) {
          if(!response.error) {
            let tasks = JSON.parse(response);
            let template = '';
            tasks.forEach(task => {
              template += `
                     <li><a href="#" class="task-item">${task.name}</a></li>
                    ` 
            });
            $('#container').html(template);
          }
        } 
      })
    }
  });

my backend with php

<?php 

include('db.php');

$search = $_POST['search'];

//buscando lo que esta en ese evento que se captura con jquery
if(!empty($search)){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE nombre_tarea LIKE '$search%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if(!$result){
        die('Query Error');
    }
    $json = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $json[]=array(
            'name' =>$row['nombre_tarea'],
            'descripcion' =>$row['descripcion'],
            'id'=>$row['id']
        );
    }
//para transformar en json
     $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
    echo $jsonString;
}else{
    echo "no hay datos";
}
?>


the response I get

[{"name":"chupayo","description":"jijasidjiasojdiojsaiodjaso","id":"1"}]

 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0**
```

Comment: Did you try adding `dataType: "json",` to your ajax?

Comment: Yes , still not working , have the same error.